# TWIG variables with HTML tags

Tags: php, twig

Is it possible to pass a variable that contains HTML content to a **[twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)** template, so when the page is rendered, HTML content from the variable is interpreted, instead of displayed with tags?

**Example:**

```
$this->_app->render('test.twig', [
            "description" => "<b>TEST</b>"
        ]);
```

**test.twig:**

```
<li><b>Description</b><br>
    {{ description }}
</li>
```

Result from the above example:

```
<b>TEST</b>
```

Expected result:

> **TEST**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the raw filter:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

```
<li><b>Description</b><br>
{{ description|raw }}
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

But be aware! When rendring, the variables shoud not be interpreted. You should take a look at [TWIG raw filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html).